# Modifying a json structure file with ruby

Tags: json, ruby, extract, collect

I tried with map and flat.map to restructure a json file (here is a sample it), with ruby from:

```
a= {
    "_nb": {
        "$nb": "55dd0"
    },
    "conf": "linux"
}
```

to

```
{
    "_nb": "55dd0",
    "conf": "linux"
}
```

or

```
{
    "$nb": "55dd0",
    "conf": "linux"
}
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction, please?

NOTE:
So far I add this solution implemented which returns a NoMethodError.. Hope this will help you both user1934428 & Cary Swoveland
..

```
    File.open("src.json", "w") do |f|  
          hash_data = JSON.parse(File.read(a))
          hash = hash_data.to_s
          hash.each do |key, value|
            if key == "_id"
              hash[value] = value.values.first
            end
          end
          f.puts(hash)
          end
```

Comment: What speaks against: (1) Parsing the file using Ruby's built-in `JSON` class, which will deliver some Hash. (2) Modifying the hash in any way you like. (3) Writing out the file again using the `JSON` class.?

Comment: The initial hash is presumably an example of the form of hashes you wish to manipulate, but you have not explained how the hash might vary. For example, could the value of `"_nb"` be `{"$nb": "55dd0", "$nc": "66ee1"}` or `{"$nb": { "$nc": "66ee1"}}`? Please clarify (by editing your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first step might be:

```
hash = {
  "_nb": {
    "$nb": "55dd0"
  },
  "conf": "linux"
}

hash.transform_values { |value| value.is_a?(Hash) ? value.values.first : value }
#=> {:_nb=>"55dd0", :conf=>"linux"}
```

Note: This only works when the nesting is not deeper than one level and when the nested array has only one key/value pair.

Comment: Thank you spickermann for you help!! But when I implemented your method I got: hash.transform_values (NoMethodError).

Comment: What does the full error message look like? Did it fail because your variable is named differently and not `hash` like in my example? Then just use your variable name instead of `hash`. Or did it fail because Ruby doesn't know the `transform_values`? Then I suggest updating Ruby because `transform_values` was introduced in Ruby 2.4.

Comment: Because of the latter. Btw, my version is up-to-date => ruby -v
ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: Please share the full error message.

Comment: undefined method `transform_values' for "src.json":String
      
            hash.transform_values { |value| value.is_a?(Hash) ? value.values.first : value }
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ (NoMethodError)

Comment: `undefined method 'transform_values' for "src.json":String` means you are calling `transform_keys` on a String and not on a Hash as expected. Please check your code why your variable is returning a String. My answer only works on a hash, like in your question.